# How to list all tags (HABTM) with number of stories in less than 2 queries in Cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I would like to be able to list the 10 most popular tags (subjects) of my site on the right menu as an element.

I however have been thinking 30 minutes about this now and unlike ending up with 1 statement to do this, I seem to be ending up with 3 statements that would drastically decrease the performance of the site.

I have a site with short stories and tags. This is a HABTM (Has-and-belongs-to-many) relationship between them using a table 'stories_tags'. A story can have multiple tags and a tag can be used by multiple stories.

The goal is listing $tagname ($storycountwiththattag), from highest number of stories per tag, to 10th highest. I have this so far, but it doesn't seem too close.

```
$tags = $this->Tag->find('all',array('fields'=>array('Tag.name')));
$tags_count = $this->Tag->Story->find('count',array('conditions'=>array('Story.tag'=>$tags)));
debug($tags_count);
```

I have tried a lot of possible queries. I could do it with restricted find('all')'s, or with:

1. Getting all ID's of all tags
2. Running 1 count-query per tag...
3. Use those results.

But I have picked Cakephp to make better applications so I wondered how you guys would do this! The site gets only a few hundred visitors daily, so performance is not extremely vital, but avoiding extremely dumb queries seems something I should try to do even if some performance penalty wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use counterCache on your tag (although you can't use with HABTM though, you'll have to define another "Tag hasMany StoriesTag" relationship. You can also [Cache](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1511/Cache) the query result.

Answer (score 0):

I make some test in the same scenario but differents ModelNames. I hope you can use it.

```
function top(){

    $options = array(
          'fields' => array('*','COUNT(CategoriesEnterprise.enterprise_id) AS num')
        , 'group' => array( 'CategoriesEnterprise.category_id' )
        , 'order' => 'num DESC'
        , 'limit' => '3'
        , 'joins' => array(array(
            'table' => 'categories',
            'alias' => 'Category',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array('CategoriesEnterprise.category_id = Category.id')
          ))
    );

    $categories = $this->Category->CategoriesEnterprise->find('all', $options);

    debug($categories);
    $this->autoRender = false;
}
```

The result

```
    Array
  (
         [0] => Array
        (
            [CategoriesEnterprise] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 3
                    [enterprise_id] => 7
                )

            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Turismo y Viajes
                    [modified] => 2011-05-16
                    [created] => 2011-04-14
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [num] => 4
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CategoriesEnterprise] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 24
                    [enterprise_id] => 5
                )

            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 24
                    [name] => Compras
                    [modified] => 2011-05-05
                    [created] => 2011-05-05
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [num] => 3
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CategoriesEnterprise] => Array
                (
                    [category_id] => 32
                    [enterprise_id] => 8
                )

            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 32
                    [name] => Salud y Belleza
                    [modified] => 2011-05-16
                    [created] => 2011-05-16
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [num] => 3
                )

        )

)
```